# Catch2 linker errors

Tags: c++, testing, clang, catch2

I've added `Catch2` as a submodule to my project and included the `Catch2/include/catch.hpp` header using the following code:

**testmain.cpp:**

```cpp
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN // This tells Catch to provide a main() - only do this in one cpp file
#include "catch.hpp"

TEST_CASE( "Test test", "[test]" ) {
    REQUIRE(true);
}
```

but I get a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "Catch::NameAndTags::NameAndTags(Catch::StringRef const&, Catch::StringRef const&)", referenced from: ___cxx_global_var_init.1 in testmain.cpp.o
```

What am I doing wrong? I thought Catch2 was supposed to be self-contained in its header and didn't need any `.cpp` file to provide its symbols?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out thanks to a [response to one of the Catch2 Github Issues](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/1149#issuecomment-360974030):

**horenmar:**

```
You are supposed to use the single-include version.

It is possible to use the headers in include/, but then you have to also compile and
link the implementation files in there and you are not provided with any guarantees
vis-a-vis stability and functionality.
```

The version in `includes/` is the original file the "real" Catch2 header is generated from. The one you're supposed to include is in `Catch2/single_include/catch2/catch.hpp`. So make sure your header search paths are set to search there for `catch.hpp`, not in `includes`.

Comment: I strongly recommend `-I Catch2/single_include` and using `#include <catch2/catch.hpp>`, as that is how they intend for you to consume the library (as opposed to `#include <catch.hpp>`). I can't remember which issue on the GitHub I saw that discussed this, but I do recall seeing it

Comment: I don't find this single_include/ folder in my installation of catch2. I'm using a MacBook and catch2 was installed using brew.